# How to compare two columns in two worksheets and get the result in a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, compare, worksheet

I am trying to compare column A and Column B of two worksheets.

When column A is compared I can get three possible results:

- Item found in "Update" but not in "Original"
- Item found in "Original" but not in "Update"
- blank when there is a match

When B is compared I can get two possible results:

- Item changed in Update
- Otherwise it is blank

```vb
Public Sub matchRow()

    Dim dumpSheet, icdSheet, outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim startRow, outputRow, tempDumpRow, tempICDRow, icdRowCount, finishedICDIndex As Integer
    Dim finishedICD() As String
    Dim isExist As Boolean

    'Set sheets
    Set dumpSheet = Sheets("Update")
    Set icdSheet = Sheets("Original")
    Set outputSheet = Sheets("Output")

    'Set start row of each sheet for data
    startRow = 1
    outputRow = 1

    'Get row count from ICD sheet
    icdRowCount = icdSheet.Range("A:B").End(xlDown).Row

    'Set index
    finishedICDIndex = 0

    'Re-define array
    ReDim finishedICD(0 To icdRowCount - 1)

    'Set the start row
    tempDumpRow = startRow

    'Here I looped with OR state, you can modify it to AND start if you want
    Do While dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow) <> ""

        'Reset exist flag
        isExist = False

        'loop all row in ICD sheet
        For tempICDRow = 1 To icdRowCount Step 1

            'If row is not finished for checking.
            If UBound(Filter(finishedICD, tempICDRow)) < 0 Then

                'If all cells of column A are equal
                If dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("A" & tempICDRow) Then

                    'Set true to exist flag
                    isExist = True

                    'Store finished row
                    finishedICD(finishedICDIndex) = tempICDRow

                    finishedICDIndex = finishedICDIndex + 1

                    'If all cells of column B are equal
                    If dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("B" & tempICDRow) Then

                        'Set true to exist flag
                        isExist = True

                        'Store finished row
                        finishedICD(finishedICDIndex) = tempICDRow

                        finishedICDIndex = finishedICDIndex + 1

                        'exit looping
                        Exit For

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next tempICDRow

        'Show result column A
        outputSheet.Range("A" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow)

        If isExist Then
            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = ""
        Else
            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""Update"" but not in ""Original"""
        End If

        'Show result column B
        outputSheet.Range("B" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow)

        If isExist Then
            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = ""
        Else
            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = "Country not the same in ""Update"" than in ""Original"""
        End If
        'increase output row
        outputRow = outputRow + 1

        'go next row
        tempDumpRow = tempDumpRow + 1

    Loop

    'loop all row in ICD sheet
    For tempICDRow = 1 To icdRowCount Step 1

        'If row is not finished for checking.
        If UBound(Filter(finishedICD, tempICDRow)) < 0 Then

            'Show result
            outputSheet.Range("A" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("A" & tempICDRow)

            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""Original"" but not in ""Update"""

            'increase output row
            outputRow = outputRow + 1

        End If

    Next tempICDRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that *"If you don't specify a **data type** (or object type, and there is no Def_type_ statement in the module), the variable is **Variant** by default."* In order to declare your sheet objects as Worksheet (and not as Variants) you have to indicate their data type one by one, e.g. `Dim dumpSheet As WorkSheet, icdSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet`. Always use `Option Explicit` to check correct declarations. Try to fully qualify your sheet/range references. Furthermore I'd prefer range related counters as of `Long` type instead of `Integer` as row numbers can exceed ~65K.

Comment: [Code copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667675/vba-compare-tables-on-2-sheets-with-differences/31694690#31694690)